# Changing temporarily sys.stdout gives " ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout, valueerror

I'm doing the examples from Marco Buttu's "Programmare con Python:Guida completa".
The objective is to temporarily change `sys.stdout` to evade pass arguments to print()

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout = open('myfile.log', 'w')
>>> print('escribo en el archivo log...')
>>> print('todavia en el archivo log...')
>>> sys.stdout.close()
>>> open('myfile.log').read()
```

and i'm getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Could someone explain to me why this is happening?
Is some error due to different versions (book version: 3.4, actual version: 3.6.5)

I'll be looking for your answers.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You've _permanently_ changed `sys.stdout`, which is why python throws an error when it tries to output something. Change `sys.stdout` back to its original value and the problem will be gone.

Comment: Related: [How do I revert sys.stdout.close()?](//stackoverflow.com/q/17743052)

Comment: Related/dupe: [Temporarily Redirect stdout/stderr](//stackoverflow.com/q/6796492)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  
First i have to revert sys.stdout back with  
    >>> sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__  
Then open the file.  
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You have been overwriting `sys.stdout` with a file handle.Since print() tries to write to `sys.stdout` it will fail.You should reset it.

This will work:

```
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```